# How do I return a custom array of objects and join some other tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have asked way too many questions on jsonb and still feel a bit lost. 
I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE _data (
  id       serial PRIMARY KEY
, data     jsonb
);

--with the following rows:
pk | data
---|------------------------
1  | {"year": 2012, "model": "honda"}
2  | {"year": 2014, "model": "toyota"}


CREATE TABLE _people (
  pk         serial PRIMARY KEY
  user       integer
, data       integer
, updated    timestamp without time zone
, documents  jsonb
);

-- with the following rows:
pk  | user   | data| updated                  | documents
----|--------|-----|--------------------------|---------------
1   | 1      | 1   | 2015-08-22 16:05:40.76   | [{"type": "spreadsheet", "title": "mySpreadsheet", "length": 1278, "ignoredKey": "ignoreme"}, {"type": "document", "title": "My Nice Title"}]
2   | 1      | 1   | 2015-08-24 16:03:00      | [{"type": "spreadsheet", "title": "anothersheet", "length": 1400, "ignoredKey": "ignoreme"}, {"type": "document", "title": "here's another document"}]



CREATE TABLE _users (
  pk       serial PRIMARY KEY
, name     text
);

-- with the following example row:

pk   | name
-----|------
1    | Jim Bob


I am trying to get the following output (notice I am ignoring some keys in my documents...specifically "ignoredKey":

User     | Data                             | Updated                   |Documents 
---------|----------------------------------|---------------------------|------------
Jim Bob  | {"year": 2012, "model": "honda"} |2015-08-22 16:05:40.764122 | [{"type": "spreadsheet", "title": "mySpreadsheet", "length": 1278}, {"type": "document", "title": "My Nice Title"}]

Jim Bob  | {"year": 2014, "model": "toyota"} |2015-08-24 16:03:00        | [{"type": "spreadsheet", "title": "anothersheet", "length": 1400}, {"type": "document", "title": "here's another document"}]
```

I have:

```
SELECT p.pk, u.name, custom_docs, d.data FROM _people p,
  jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents) doc(type text, title text, length numeric)
  LEFT JOIN _data d ON p.data = d.pk
  LEFT JOIN _users u ON p.user = u.pk
```

Which gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "p"
LINE 3:   LEFT JOIN _data d ON p.data = d.pk
                               ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

EDIT #1:

As pointed below I need the "Documents" column that is created to be an array of objects...in the form of:

```
[{"type": "spreadsheet", "title": "mySpreadsheet", "length": 1278}, {"type": "document", "title": "My Nice Title"}]
```

Any other format is hard to use once it is retrieved.

EDIT #2:
Dmitry's answer helped get me further along but the "Documents" column contains ALL of the documents from all rows rather than those I need:

```
WITH docs AS (
  SELECT array_agg(to_json(changed_structure)) as changed_json_array
  FROM _people p,jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents) AS changed_structure(type text, title text, length numeric)
)
SELECT u.name,d.data,p.updated,docs.changed_json_array FROM docs,_people p
LEFT JOIN _users u ON u.pk = p.user
LEFT JOIN _data d ON d.pk = p.data;
```

This gives me:

```
name    | data                              | updated                    | documents
------- | ----------------------------------| ---------------------------|
Jim Bob | {"year": 2012, "model": "honda"}  | 2015-08-22 16:05:40.764122 | {"{\"type\":\"spreadsheet\",\"title\":\"mySpreadsheet\",\"length\":1278}","{\"type\":\"document\",\"title\":\"My Nice Title\",\"length\":null}","{\"type\":\"spreadsheet\",\"title\":\"anothersheet\",\"length\":1400}","{\"type\":\"document\",\"title\":\"here's another document\",\"length\":null}"} 
Jim Bob | {"year": 2014, "model": "toyota"} | 2015-08-24-16:03:00        | {"{\"type\":\"spreadsheet\",\"title\":\"mySpreadsheet\",\"length\":1278}","{\"type\":\"document\",\"title\":\"My Nice Title\",\"length\":null}","{\"type\":\"spreadsheet\",\"title\":\"anothersheet\",\"length\":1400}","{\"type\":\"document\",\"title\":\"here's another document\",\"length\":null}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key motive here is to use `json_agg(to_json(doc))` from `jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents)`:

```
select pk, json_agg(to_json(doc)) doc
from _people p, jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents) doc(type text, title text, length numeric)
group by 1

 pk |                                                                doc                                                
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"type":"spreadsheet","title":"mySpreadsheet","length":1278}, {"type":"document","title":"My Nice Title","length":null}]
  2 | [{"type":"spreadsheet","title":"anothersheet","length":1400}, {"type":"document","title":"heres another document","length":null}]
(2 rows)
```

and appropriate use of the join:

```
select u.name, d.data, p.updated, s.doc
from _people p
left join _users u on u.pk = p.auser
left join _data d on d.pk = p.data
left join (
    select pk, json_agg(to_json(doc)) doc
    from _people p, jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents) doc(type text, title text, length numeric)
    group by 1
    ) s on s.pk = p.pk

  name   |               data               |        updated         |                                                                doc
---------+----------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Jim Bob | {"year": 2012, "model": "honda"} | 2015-08-22 16:05:40.76 | [{"type":"spreadsheet","title":"mySpreadsheet","length":1278}, {"type":"document","title":"My Nice Title","length":null}]
 Jim Bob | {"year": 2012, "model": "honda"} | 2015-08-24 16:03:00    | [{"type":"spreadsheet","title":"anothersheet","length":1400}, {"type":"document","title":"heres another document","length":null}]
(2 rows)
```

Note: I had to change `_users.user` to `_users.auser`.

Answer (score 0):

## [changed]

```
WITH docs AS (
  SELECT array_agg(to_json(changed_structure)) as changed_json_array
  FROM _people p,jsonb_to_recordset(p.documents) AS changed_structure(type text, title text, length numeric)
)
SELECT u.name,d.data,p.updated,docs.changed_json_array FROM docs,_people p
LEFT JOIN _users u ON u.pk = p.user
LEFT JOIN _data d ON d.id = p.data;
```

Comment: updated the answer, pay attention to `p.user` - it didn't let me run your DDL for `_people` table. I guess this is my machine specific. @kristen

Comment: very close but changed_json_array gives me a weird object...how do I get an array of objects?

Comment: {} it's known psql notation, will check later as I'm writing from the phone :)

Comment: If you check [array aggregation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) docs and  [array type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) you will see that `{1,2,3,4}` is valid array declaration @kristen

Comment: it might be valid but it doesn't answer the question.